# l1 magic error - matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, cvx

I am trying to reconstruct the image using fewer observations than the dimensions of the signal(compressed sensing). I am trying to run the following piece of code -

```
A = imread('cameraman.png');

x_i = 37;
y_i = 95;
s = 35;

A = A([x_i:x_i+s],[y_i:y_i+s]);
x = double(A(:));
figure(1),imshow(A)
xlabel('original')
n=length(x);
m=floor(n/3);
Phi=randn(m,n);   %Measurment Matrix
Psi=dftmtx(n);   %sensing Matrix( or can be dct(eye(n)) )
y=Phi*x;  %compressed signal
Theta=Phi*Psi;
%Initial Guess:  y=Theta*s => s=Theta\y
s2=Theta\y;
%Solution
s1=l1qc_logbarrier(s2, Theta,[], y, 1e-1, 1e-1);
%Reconstruction
x1=Psi*s1;
figure,imshow(reshape(x1,size(A)), [0 256] ),xlabel('OMP')
```

However on running the code I get the following error.

```
Error using linsolve
Matrix must be positive definite.

Error in l1qc_newton (line 92)
    [dx,hcond] = linsolve(H11p, w1p, opts);

Error in l1qc_logbarrier (line 104)
  [xp, up, ntiter] = l1qc_newton(x, u, A, At, b, epsilon, tau, newtontol,
  newtonmaxiter, cgtol, cgmaxiter);

Error in cs_image2 (line 23)
s1=l1qc_logbarrier(s2, Theta,[], y, 1e-1, 1e-1);
```

The above piece of code recovers the solution when the sensing matrix is the dct matrix instead of dft matrix. Could someone point me to where the error lies? Is it a problem inherent to l1-magic? Will using a different solver work for me?

**Note**: l1qc_logbarrier is a function from the library l1 magic. http://users.ece.gatech.edu/justin/l1magic/index.html

l1qc_logbarrier solves -

[image: l1 minimization]

Comment: What is `l1qc_logbarrier` ?? Include its code in your post!

Comment: l1qc_barrier is a function from the library l1 magic. http://users.ece.gatech.edu/justin/l1magic/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to have come because of using the dftmtx which outputs a matrix whose elements are **complex** numbers and l1-magic doesn't work for that case. The problem I was trying to solve is l1-minimization -

[image]

Here [image: psi] is complex. So l1-magic fails. To get over it, I made the following adjustments. Let [image] , where R is the real and C the imaginary part of [image: psi] and similarly, let [image]. This gives,

[image]

We know that b is real, therefore,

[image]

Merging the 2 constraints, we get,

[image]

This gives us a single **real** constraint of the form [image] which can be solved using l1-magic.

Comment: In Matlab, it would look something like this:

R = real(Theta);
C = imag(Theta);
Theta2 = [R -C ; C R];

s1=l1qc_logbarrier([s2;...
     zeros(length(s1), 1)],...
     Theta,[],...
     [y; zeros(length(y), 1)], 1e-1, 1e-1);

Notice that the last half of s1 is basically useless information and should be discarded.

Comment: @pyronic I used the modification you posted above but didn't get a reasonable result. Can you post your code?

Comment: This was a long time ago and I don't have the code with me now. I would recommend you share more details so that the community can help you. @student1